# WebDriver chosen by user input for Selenium Tests using TestNG suites

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to integrate `Scanner()` class within my existing Selenium test cases so the users can choose the WebDriver to run the tests on and the value I believe would need to be passed to the TestNG suite.

I wanted to know if there's a way for me to pass the value from the **selectDriver** Java method to the **browser** parameter that I am using within the **TestSuite.xml**

Below is what I already have in place and also what I have tried implementing:

**selectDriver**

```
public static String selectDriver() {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select a platform and a device to run the tests on:\n" +
            "Windows\n" +
            "\t1. Google Chrome\n" +
            "\t2. Firefox\n" +
            "\t3. Microsoft Edge\n\n" +
            "Android\n" +
            "\t4. Google Chrome");

    int driverSelection = reader.nextInt();

    if (driverSelection == 1) {
        return "chromeWindows";
    } else if (driverSelection == 2) {
        return "firefoxWindows";
    } else if (driverSelection == 3) {
        return "edgeWindows";
    } else if (driverSelection == 4) {
        return "chromeAndroid";
    }
    reader.close();
    return null;
}
```

**webDriver**

```
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeClass
public void webDriver(String browser) throws IOException {

    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chromeWindows")) {

        List<String> driverArguments = List.of("start-maximized", "remote-debugging-port=9222", "disable-popup-blocking", "disable-notifications", "--remote-allow-origins=*"); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentUserDirectory + Config.config("chromeDriverPath"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
        options.addArguments(driverArguments);
        setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
```

**TestSuite.xml**

```
    !DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"
suite name="Desktop - Selenium Tests"

    parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/

    <test name="Test1" >
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.desktop.homePageTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

If there's no easier way to achieve that, I'll have to take a look into editing an XML file based on the user's input to provide the **browser** value.

Comment: @JeffC I have updated the post with my question and I hope it's more clear now.

Update: "I wanted to know if there's a way for me to pass the value from the **selectDriver** method to the **browser** parameter that I am using within the **TestSuite.xml**"

Comment: TestSuite.xml is just one way to pass in a driver. You can just write code that processes the input from Scanner(), creates a driver of that flavor, and runs the test/suite.

Comment: @JeffC I have tried to implement the **selectDriver** method within my **webDriver** method that has the **@BeforeClass** annotation while also removing the **browser** parameter. However, I am given a read-only console when running the tests. Any idea of what the issue is or how should I proceed with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about it the wrong way. I think the ideal way is to set up a release in whatever system you are using to trigger tests. Each release would specify all the expected settings... driver, resolutions, etc. and then if someone wants to start a run, they trigger the release corresponding to the driver/settings they want run.

Comment: Apologies for being difficult, but I'm not that experienced neither with Java, nor with Selenium. Is there a chance for you to share a short code snippet on what I would need to implement in each method?